# How to copy data from an old Hive cluster to a new Hive cluster and keep all Hive metastore meta data?

Tags: hadoop, hive, distcp

I have two different Apache Hive clusters and I need to transfer data from the old to the new. What is the best way to accomplish this? The old cluster is using `hive 1.2` with `hadoop 2.7` and the new is using hive `3.1` with hadoop `3.3.4`

I've tried uisng distcp but it did not work and the data did not copy to the new cluster.

Comment: Did you use hdfs:// or webhdfs:// when trying to run distcp? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.1/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html#Copying_Between_Versions_of_HDFS

Comment: Distcp will only copy the hdfs data but to copy HSM data you need to sync both of them by reading the HMS data at source and writing to destination.